# Overlapping multiple setTimeouts inside jQuery

Tags: jquery, settimeout

new here and new to jQuery. I've searched for an answer to my question/ problem without success, so here I come. I'm having problems with this code:

```
<p>Hello.</p>
<p>Good bye.</p>
<p>Ciao!</p>
<script>
jQuery('p').mouseover(
    function() {
        jQuery(this).css({backgroundColor:'red'});
    }
);
jQuery('p').mouseout(
    function() {
        myElement = jQuery(this);
        setTimeout(function(){
            color = ['red','green','blue','orange'];
            myElement.css({backgroundColor:color[Math.round(Math.random()*3)]});
        }, 1000
        )
    }
);
</script>
```

The thing is that if we move the cursor over a new paragraph before the last setTimeout function has been executed, then both the first and the second setTimeout functions will act upon the last affected paragraph. For example:

a) Move the cursor over/out a paragraph. Before the setTimeout function associated with the mouseout event is executed,

b) move the cursor over/out a different paragraph. Now the setTimeout function

```
myElement.css({backgroundColor:color[Math.round(Math.random()*3)]});
```

will select TWICE consecutively a background color for the second paragraph, and none for the first one. I've tried to associate two different vars (myElementOne and myElementTwo) with the jQuery(this) value to no avail. I would appreciate greatly some help. Thanks.

Comment: Yon can use the `hover()` method: http://jsbin.com/eciqiw/edit#javascript,html,live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `myElement` variable is defined in the [global scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable), and each `mouseout` execution overwrites the previous value of it.

If you defined `myElement` with `var myElement = jQuery(this);`, `myElement` will be defined only in the scope of the current `mouseout` event - and will affect only that element in the timeout callback.

Comment: Well, of course you're right. This is the first time I post in this site and really I don't know if it is considered of good or bad tone to reply just to say thanks, but well, thanks. I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, `myElement` becomes global and only refers to one div at any time. Add `var` in front of it to make it refer to the particular `this` in time.

```
jQuery('p').mouseout(
    function() {
        var myElement = jQuery(this);
        ...
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/m6f6b/)